# rails active_admin showing user as an ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Im trying to figure out why is nested resource is shown as an ActiveRecord relation in active admin panel. Ideally, I would like to choice an `User` of the `Listing` by an email

[image]

User is deined as

```
t.integer  "user_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a method named `display_name` on your User model which returns email of the user or any else text you want to use to represent the user.